# Squeeze Theorem on non trig functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I know this question is very broad, but if I were to use the squeeze theorem on a non trigonometric function, how would I find the bounds?

For example:

$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x^2+2}{2x-3}}$

By bounds I mean in the theorem: $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$

How to find $f(x)$ and $h(x)$

Comment: It depends on context, although I'm not sure why you would want to use the squeeze theorem in this context.

Comment: It's not that I would, I was only wondering if possible, and how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are under the impression that squeeze theorem can be used anywhere. The conditions of Squeeze theorem give the context under which it can be used. And as should be evident from the statement of the theorem that it is not restricted to trigonometric functions.

Rather if you are able to find simple (in form and whose limits are easy to evaluate) functions which bound the given function from above and below then you can apply this theorem. This does not mean that you have to become extra imaginative and try to bound every function in this manner and apply squeeze to find the limit. In fact it may happen that finding the bounds may become a more difficult problem than finding the limit itself.

For your current question the basic algebra of limits suffices. In general when the algebra of limit does not work then you need to go for tools like Squeeze and the more advanced ones like L'Hospital's Rule and Taylor's series.

In any case here is one try. Decrease the fraction by adding $x^2$ in numerator and thus you get the inequality $$\frac{2x^2+2}{2x-3}<\frac{x^2+2}{2x-3}<\frac{2}{2x-3}$$ and Squeeze theorem works but there is no extra advantage.

Comment: Good explanation! I just wanted to point out you accidentally reversed the inequalities there at the end.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp: they are intentionally like that: the denominator is negative as $x\to 0$ so the inequalities are correct.

Comment: Oh you are correct. I guess I'm more tired than I thought